# Counting no. of filled rows in Access Db

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using the following code for fetching the no. of filled rows in MS Access Db. But I am getting the following error at open command

```
public static int CountRecordsInAccess(string ResultFile)//TODO
        {
            string ResultFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + ResultFile;
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" + ";Data Source=" + ResultFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
            //Create Connection 
            OleDbConnection AccessConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            AccessConnection.Open();
            //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table1" , AccessConnection);

            int rows = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            AccessConnection.Close();
            return rows;
        }
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong

Comment: could you post the error ? and are you hitting an excel file or an access db ?

Comment: I am accessing a db and the error at open is " External table is not in the expected format."

Comment: in your extended properties you are specifying "Excel"

Comment: I even tried with Access in the Extended properties but there got the error " could not find the installed ISAM". Do I need to add something else in the Extended properties.

Comment: remove the extended properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" + ";Data Source=" + ResultFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False";
```